# How to save different matrices in a variable using R?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to save different matrices into one variable, like an array, for example:
I have matrix 1:

```
ma1<-matrix(c(1:8),4)
```

and matrix 2:

```
ma2<-matrix(c(2,1,3,4,5,6,4,5),4)
```

Now, I want to save these matrices into one more dimensional variable, so like this:

```
multiarray<-0
multiarray[1]<-ma1
multiarray[2]<-ma2
```

(I want to do this later on with a loop.)

It would be important, that the single output, e.g. multiarray[1] is again a matrix.
How can I do this?

Comment: You can have multidimensional arrays, but usually this is best done with a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple list would suffice

```
ma1<-matrix(c(1:8),4)
ma2<-matrix(c(2,1,3,4,5,6,4,5),4)
ma3<-matrix(runif(8),4)
```

either assign like this:

```
multiarray = list(ma1,ma2);
```

or in a loop

```
multiarray = list();
for(...){
   multiarray[[i]] = maX;
}
```

or by name

```
multiarray = list();     
multiarray$something = ma3; # ma3 will implicitly have first index 1
```

the output is a matrix

```
multiarray[[1]]
```

Comment: this does not work, if I do  multiarray[[1]]<-ma1 and  multiarray[[2]]<-ma2
 I get the error message (german): "  mehr Elemente gegeben als zu ersetzen sind" wich means something like more elements given as to be substituted

Comment: ah ok, I guess I have to put the following command before: multiarray<-list(NA)

Comment: Yes, exactly, define it as a list first. multiarray <- list();